# Can you sign your APK again once you lost the Password accidentally , My laptop died?

Tags: android

So back in 2015 I managed to develop an Android app and I was able to launch it on the app store, but then I did not use Github much so my backup was my laptop, my laptop later died and I lost everything, So I have been unable to update my app or do anything but thanks to this question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file) I was able to download my apk.

My new question now is since I lost the key , is it possible to generate a new Signed APK ? or how can I retrieve the lost password. Or what can i do? I got a notification today about the Android targetSdkVersion, so my app does not meet that and I would love to update it.

The app doesn't break and I got good reviews and it has 500+ downloads, just wondering what I should do.

Comment: No, you are going to have add a new app on playstore.

Comment: There is nothing you can do now , just recreate the app using new package name and keystore , remove old app ,publish new app and start over again

Comment: Ouch that is really sad. Wish It was much easier.